# Why there is no current flowing through the boost converter to the DC motor?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, dc-motor, boost, low-power

I am trying to make a boost converter to boost a low voltage from a solar cell to power a low power DC motor.

[image: Circuit Image]

I want to power a DC motor using a single solar cell, that can only provide about 0.5-0.6 V and 1.2 A (this is the restricting case). The motor itself can start with only about 1.2 V and 0.3 A, so basically I just want to double the voltage (or triple if possible). For the project I am working on, I cannot use integrated boost circuits, because they have a regulated output. The converter I want is some kind of voltage multiplier, where if the input decreases, the output also decreases.

The equipment I used are:

- DMG2302UK-7 MOSFET. ([Datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMG2302UK.pdf))
- 1N5817 Schottky diode.
- 1 mH/2 A inductor.
- 330 uF electrolyte capacitor.

The PWM that I used is 10 kHz with 50% duty cycle. The MOSFET gate is driven by an Arduino powered by an external battery, so driving the MOSFET should not be a problem. For testing the circuit, I am using a DC power supply as a source with voltage limiting mode (0.6 V). However, during testing, there seems almost no current flowing to the circuit, as the following picture suggests. What did I do wrong, can anyone help me?

[image: DC Power Supply Image]

Comment: You have 0.6 to 0.72 W from the solar panel absolute peak. What are you really getting from the solar panel? Put a resistor eaqual to that of the motor's stall reistance across the panel and measure votlage and current. I don't think you have enough power from the panel to power the motor. It isn't votlage or current that's lacking, it's power.

Comment: Welcome! Please measure the solar panel voltage and current when connected. Your boost converter does not feature MPPT, so my guess it that it loads it down way too hard, voltage drops to nothing, boost converter restarts due to UVLO and cycle repeats.

Comment: I tested this circuit with a DC Power Supply (in the second image is the source), so the supply power should not be a problem. Also, I am going to use a laser to power the solar panel, so reaching the absolute peak power is possible.

Comment: Turning a MOSFET fully on and off with 0.6 V - about minimum threshold gate-source voltage - should prove difficult. Check out [Joule thieves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief).

Comment: The MOSFET will be driven by Arduino with external battery, so it should not be a problem. I also edited the post to provide this information. This is my first time in this forum, sorry if am not detailed enough in explaining my situation.

Comment: (*What did I do wrong?* Solder wires to screw terminals. Show a section not allowing to check power connections. Present no schematic.)

Comment: Does the PS display show current *measured* or *limit selected*?

Comment: The PS display shows the current measured, because only the voltage is limited to 0.6V (The red lamp on the voltage knob). The current is not limited.

Comment: That inductor you're using looks unsuitable for use in a boost converter circuit. What are is current and series resistance specs?

Comment: @brhans Good catch! 0 % chance of that guy being 1 mH with 2 A saturation current.